# Python Merge 2 DICT objects if matching id within a list with separators

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, match, partial

In Python I have those 2 dicts objects :

```
dict1 = [{'id_contact': '1', 'name': 'Rick'},{'id_contact': '9', 'name': 'John'}]

dict2 = [{'id_company': ';1;3;4;11;', 'company_name': 'Nike'},{'id_company': ';1;2;9;', 'company_name': 'Adidas'}]
```

I would like to merge those 2 dicts to a new one to add the `'company_name'` if `id_contact` of dict1 is found in `id_company` in dict2.
If theres is several matches **I would like to use **";"** as a separator in** `'company_name'`.

The expected result would be :

```
dictmerge = [{'id_contact': '1', 'name': 'Rick', 'company_name': 'Nike;Adidas'},{'id_contact': '9', 'name': 'John', 'company_name': 'Adidas'}]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of these inputs? Since both are lists the most efficient solution you can have is going to be O(n^2). Why not make at least one of them a dict? Assuming `id_contact` is unique, `dict1` can actually be a dict and not a list

Comment: Unfortunately no I cannot change the way the dicts are generated. That’s why I’ m asking for help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Initial note: `dict1` and `dict1` are **lists** (of dictionaries), not dictionaries.*

You need a few steps, first loop over `dict2` to aggregate the company names per ID, then flatten this as a string. Finally, loop over `dict1` and add the missing key:

```
companies = {}
for d in dict2:
    for i in d.get('id_company', '').strip(';').split(';'):
        companies.setdefault(i, []).append(d['company_name'])
companies = {i: ';'.join(v) for i, v in companies.items()}
# {'1': 'Nike;Adidas', '3': 'Nike', '4': 'Nike', '11': 'Nike',
#  '2': 'Adidas', '9': 'Adidas'}

for d in dict1:
    d['company_name'] = companies.get(d['id_contact'])

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
[{'id_contact': '1', 'name': 'Rick', 'company_name': 'Nike;Adidas'},
 {'id_contact': '9', 'name': 'John', 'company_name': 'Adidas'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like this solution. Last question before I accept it, how would you adapt this answer if ever there was no match ? like for example if there was this in dict1 : {'id_contact': '5', 'name': 'Donna'} , the ID 5 wouldn't match with any of the dict2 IDS. So I would like the result to be in this case : {'id_contact': '5', 'name': 'Donna', 'company_name': ''} but so far it creates an error "can' find variable: None"

Comment: Nevermind, I succed by modifying this in your answer :         for d in dict1:
            if companies.get(d['id_contact']) == None:
                d['company_name'] = ' '
            else:
                d['company_name'] = companies.get(d['id_contact'])

Comment: You can directly use: `d['company_name'] = companies.get(d['id_contact'], '')` ;)

Comment: Thanks I will modify the answer. And thank you for the initial note, i learned something too and try to won't make the mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to keep id_company in list and instead of creating new disc, add new field in dict1 for company name.

Now the code will look like this,

```
peopleDict = [
{
    'id_contact': 1, 
    'name': 'Rick',
    'company_name': [],
 },
{
    'id_contact': 9, 
    'name': 'John',
    'company_name': [],
}
]

companyDict = [
    {
        'id_company': [1,3,4,11], 
        'company_name': 'Nike'
        },
    {
        'id_company': [1,2,9], 
        'company_name': 'Adidas'
    }
]

for person in peopleDict:
    for company in companyDict:
        if person.get('id_contact') in company.get('id_company'):
            person['company_name'].append(company.get('company_name'))

print(peopleDict)
```